# Test confirmation promise with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I would like to test this with Jest

```
const accept = () => 
  new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {
    const acceptBtn = document.getElementById('accept');
    acceptBtn.onclick => () => resolve(true);
})
test('should return true', async() => {
  const spyDocument = jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById');
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.id = 'accept';
  btn.click = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true));
  spyDocument.mockReturnValue(img);
  const accepted = await accept();
  expect(accepted).toBe(true);
```

I receive timeout error here. Can someone have look on this and point what is wrong with this implementation?

Comment: Where does `img` come from?

Comment: I edited this to `btn` (typed as img by mistake)